Why there is no type for PasteEvent in types/jquery?
Why there is no type for PasteEvent or ClipboardEvent in types/jquery?
There is standard type for paste event (ClipboardEvent) but not for jquery event.
enter image description here
enter image description here
Tried searching info about it but couldn't find any...

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

PasteEvent and ClipboardEvent types are not part of JQuery (perhaps of the @types/jquery version)
You could update the code similar like this:
const foo = (event: ClipboardEvent): File[] => {
  // Your implementation
}

If you need to work with jQuery-specific event handling, you might need to cast the event type explicitly:
const foo = (event: JQuery.Event): File[] => {
  const clipboardEvent = event as ClipboardEvent
  // Your implementation
};

also make sure to install npm i -D @types/jquery
